# Standards compliant way to remove arrow from Select?

Tags: html, css, standards

On `<select>` menus how can you use the webkit and moz appearance CSS properties to remove the default drop down arrow, but that is not compliant with IE/Edge nor is standards compliant - as it looks like the W3C has decided **NOT** to include it now or any time soon.

I know IE has their own specific way of removing the drop down arrow with

```
select::-ms-expand { display:none }
```

I was just wondering if anyone had any better - more standards-compliant ways to do the same thing.